# Full-width container on mobile

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

guys!
I have a website with the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- some code here -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="screenFourth">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- a lot of tags -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So the problem is that if I open the website on mobile it has a empty space on the right side of the screen. Here is the image of it:
[Empty space on the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dl7C.png)

css code is the following:

```
.screenFourth{
    background-image: url(...);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top;
    min-height: 1380px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 760px){
    .container{ width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; }
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: .screenFourth: 100vw;

Comment: Can you post url of the image ?

Comment: @VladoPandžić click on "Empty space on the right side" link.

Comment: @Gerard it stays the same.

Answer (score 3):

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.screenFourth{
    background-image: url(...);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1380px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 760px){
    .container{ width: 100vw; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
}
```

Add the following to your CSS File. I've set the background width to 100%,
And added `width: 100vw;` to the container CSS. `vw` is a css unit which sets the width relative to the view port. I hope this help.

Also took out the margin & padding off from HTML and Body tag.

EDIT HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- some code here -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="screenFourth">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- a lot of tags -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is still the same. Nothing changed.

Comment: @tohhy sorry I just edited the answer, could you check it out again

Comment: thank you, but I did nothing, it somehow worked. Maybe it's because of Chrome cache.